# Duplicate then concatenate in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

How do I join `a` to both sides of `:` to result in `a:a`?

I could use something like `=join(":","a","a")`, but in this case, my `"a"` is another formula and it is very long. I'm trying to find a way so I don't have to write the formula twice.

Something like

`=join(":",rept("a",2))` → but this produces `aa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula.

### Formula

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REPT(A1 & ":",2),".$","")
```

### Explained

First the following string is being repeated twice: `RESULT_OF_A1` combined with a semicolon.
The last semicolon in this repetition is being removed by the `REGEXREPLACE` formula. It simply replaces the last character by an empty space. The result of your formula is being used only once.

Comment: unfortunately that won't work, that is the same thing as `=CONCATENATE(A1, ":", A1)`. I'm trying to keep in the same cell with one formula only. In this case, the `A1` formula will be called twice.

Comment: @jason_cant_code How about this?

Comment: Both `A` has to be produced by a formula. I'm trying to avoid typing in the formula twice. I also want to keep it in one cell.

Comment: Works. Nice solution.